FATAL:..\flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/gles/proc_table_gles.h(39) Fatal GL Error GL_INVALID_VALUE(1281) encountered on call to glTexImage2D
When running my Flutter app, I encounter this error:
> Launching lib\\main.dart on Windows in debug mode... √ Built
> build\\windows\\x64\\runner\\Debug\\perfume_finder.exe Connecting to
> VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:49631/Z4KZ6agj2vw=/ws
> \[FATAL:..\\flutter/impeller/renderer/backend/gles/proc_table_gles.h(39)\]
> Fatal GL Error GL_INVALID_VALUE(1281) encountered on call to
> glTexImage2D
>
> Lost connection to the device.
>
> Exited.

I even run flutter run -no--impeller
but still, the error persists!

Is this a new project without any custom code?

This should be resolved in version 3.24.2, at least, per this comment reply by the issue raiser on the relevant GitHub issue.

I saw a number of reports like this, for example. Seems like this problem is reproducible on relatively old devices (Intel core 2 duo and similar, or older). However, I won't make assumptions about OP's hardware, since it's not 100% proved that it is all about old hardware.
As far as I understand, based on PR claiming to fix this problem, problem is in relations between Skia engine and relatively old GPU's with OpenGL ES 2.0.
What to do?

Downgrade Flutter. It can work based on some reports from GitHub issues. However, version to downgrade you have to determine yourself.
Wait until this PR lands. It claims to fix such problems with windows, and it even tested on some customer's old hardware, so chances are high :) It should happen very soon (in fact, many hoped this fix will land in latest 3.24.0), but we do not have exact date of course.

